# geometry materials in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a geometry in THREE.js:

```
var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
dotGeometry.dynamic = true;

var createDot = function (group, x, y, z){
    group.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z));
}

var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var gap = 0.1;

for(var i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < height; j++){
        createDot(dotGeometry, i*gap, j*gap, 0);
    }
}
```

as long as I use the points material, everything works fine - I can see my geometry:

```
var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 1, color: 0xffffff, sizeAttenuation: false } );
var dot = new THREE.Points( dotGeometry, dotMaterial );
scene.add( dot );
```

but as soon as I want to use any other material to see something like a "solid" surface, I can't see anything, for example:

```
var dotMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
var dot = new THREE.Points( dotGeometry, dotMaterial );
scene.add( dot );
```

does `geometry` only work together with `PointsMaterial` or what am I doing wrong?

Example 1: Working

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
dotGeometry.dynamic = true;

var createDot = function (group, x, y, z){
    group.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z));
}

var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var gap = 0.1;

for(var i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < height; j++){
        createDot(dotGeometry, i*gap, j*gap, 0);
    }
}

var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 1, color: 0xffffff, sizeAttenuation: false } );
var dot = new THREE.Points( dotGeometry, dotMaterial );

scene.add( dot );
scene.add(light);

camera.position.z = 5;
light.position.y = 2;
light.position.z = 5;
light.position.x = 0;

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  dot.rotation.x += 0.01;
  dot.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
```

Example 2: Not working

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
dotGeometry.dynamic = true;

var createDot = function (group, x, y, z){
    group.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z));
}

var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var gap = 0.1;

for(var i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < height; j++){
        createDot(dotGeometry, i*gap, j*gap, 0);
    }
}

var dotMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
var dot = new THREE.Points( dotGeometry, dotMaterial );

scene.add( dot );
scene.add(light);

camera.position.z = 5;
light.position.y = 2;
light.position.z = 5;
light.position.x = 0;

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  dot.rotation.x += 0.01;
  dot.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would you be able to provide a minimal example?

Comment: @JuanFerrer minimal example of what?

Comment: Minimal example of the code needed to replicate the problem. A CodePen, a Fiddle or the like.

Comment: @JuanFerrer all the code is in my question. you just need to include the three-library. haven't got the time to build a fiddle right now, I maybe will provide one later.

Comment: Just a note, you can also use StackOverflow's "snippet" (the button beside _Insert image_) functionality do provide your working example, without the dependence on a third-party site.

Comment: @TheJim01 then show me an example on how to include the three.js library in that snippet please.

Comment: @low_rents I edited your question to add the 2 snippets. That is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Something you could do is use your `geometry.vertices` to populate a [`ConvexGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/geometries/ConvexGeometry) (you will need to link to [ConvexGeometry.js](https://threejs.org/examples/js/geometries/ConvexGeometry.js) and [QuickHull.js](https://threejs.org/examples/js/QuickHull.js)).

You create your geometry as you did before

```
dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

Then you will need to pass that onto your `ConvexGeometry` like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.ConvexGeometry(dotGeometry.vertices);
```

After that, you apply your material as usual.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Here's an example in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/yzapxz);

This is assuming you need a convex shape. If you just need a plane, use a [`PlaneGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/PlaneGeometry).

r87

Comment: thank you. i already stumbled over this method when googling.. the problem is - i can't manage to get `ConvexGeometry.js` and `QuickHull.js` to work in npm.